# Meteor new field in mongoDB collection work in js file but not in html template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor, collections

I added a new field to all my documents in a `mongoDB` collection of my Meteor project via `robo3T`, I can use/read new field via `console.log` in `js` file but `{{new field}}` in `html`  temaplate does not work and I can't figure why.. all others fields work completely fine.

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read in the help me section on how to ask a proper question. In general we need some code example on issues such as yours. In your concrete case this means: code snippet of the html template, the template js code and your the code of your server publication (if you have autopublish disabled). Otherwise it will be very hard to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing a helper to return that data for the template? Something like this should work.

```
Template.example.helpers({
newfield: function(){
 return Newfields.find({});
}
});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<template name = 'example'>
{{#each newfield}}
<p>{{New Field Data}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

This should do what you're looking for!

If you need more help or want to see it in action I have a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmkzSLK2Dbk) which implements this in a full application. There is also the blaze docs [here](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html) which might be helpful.

Maybe next time it would helpful if there is some code provided as I can only presume what you are looking for.

Felix.